# How use Filters with boto3 vpc endpoint services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I need to get vpc endpoint service ID from python script, but I don't understand how use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=vpc_endpoint_services#EC2.Client.describe_vpc_endpoint_services), filters from vpc-id or a subnet

How do I use Filters?

This part of boto3

```
> (dict) --
A filter name and value pair that is used to return a more specific list of results from a describe operation. Filters can be used to match a set of resources by specific criteria, such as tags, attributes, or IDs. The filters supported by a describe operation are documented with the describe operation. For example:
DescribeAvailabilityZones
DescribeImages
DescribeInstances
DescribeKeyPairs
DescribeSecurityGroups
DescribeSnapshots
DescribeSubnets
DescribeTags
DescribeVolumes
DescribeVpcs
Name (string) --
The name of the filter. Filter names are case-sensitive.

Values (list) --
The filter values. Filter values are case-sensitive.

(string) --
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method would be to call it with no filters, and observe what comes back:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_vpc_endpoint_services()

for service in response['ServiceDetails']:
    print(service['ServiceId'])
```

You can then either filter the results within your Python code, or use the `Filters` capability of the Describe command.

Feel free to `print(response)` to see the data that comes back.

Comment: Thanks 

Finaly, i export EndpointService ID in my cfn template.
and get it with : 
def _find_export_recursively(name):
    response = cloudformationclient.list_exports()['Exports']
    search = list(filter(lambda x: x['Name'] == name, response))
    #print (search)
    if len(search) > 0:
        return search[0]['Value']
    else:
        return None

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to filter the results with. In my case, I use below to filter it for a specific vpc-endpoint-id.

```py
import boto3

vpc_client = boto3.client('ec2')
vpcEndpointId = "vpce-###"
vpcEndpointDetails = vpc_client.describe_vpc_endpoints(
    VpcEndpointIds=[vpcEndpointId],
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'vpc-endpoint-id',
            'Values': [vpcEndpointId]
        },
    ])
```